# How to remove/install a package that is not fully installed?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, aptitude

I went to install `bsnes` the other day and, for whatever reason, the installation failed. Now, I cannot update, install new packages, or do basically any apt-get commands as they all try to process this broken package and fail. Attempting to install a new package also just dooms it to the same fate.

The error I get is:

```
Setting up google-chrome-stable (33.0.1750.152-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable.postinst: 124: /var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable.postinst: update-alternatives: not found
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up bsnes (0.088-7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/bsnes.postinst: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/bsnes.postinst: update-alternatives: not found
dpkg: error processing bsnes (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
 bsnes
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have been searching on Google and here on Ask Ubuntu but have not found a working solution.

The commonly suggested fix is to run the following:

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This however does not work. The apt-get commands all fail with the same error as above and the dpkg command just doesn't help. The other thing they often suggest to purge it via Synaptic or the command line, which also fails.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So, after more googling and really carefully reading through the error messages again it seems that `dpkg` needed to be reinstalled.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```

What tipped off that this was the problem (if anyone searches and sees this) is that `update-alternatives: not found` was in the error message. As soon as dpkg was reinstalled, the other packages proceeded to install normally automatically.

Comment: Why is the only correct (and accepted) answer so far down the list with less than ⅓ of the votes of the top answer? +1

Comment: for one: because it doesn't work for packages which can no longer be downloaded "Reinstallation of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-65-generic is not possible, it cannot be downloaded."

Comment: This is probably the _least_ likely solution for anyone coming here based on the title of the question. But there are a lot of reasons one can end up with this problem, so there _will_ be a lot of proposed "this works for me" solutions.

Comment: This doesn't actually work.

Comment: The only one that worked for me of so many others

Comment: I had a problem with an older version of package that was interfering with my current version. It wasn't getting uninstalled properly because I tried to install the newer version. This helped correct the older installation. then I removed it completely and installed the new version

Comment: Great find! This helped a lot, as did the response from Hamed!

Answer (score 108):

**For advanced users, use at your own risks.**

According to the following error message :

```
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

You may want to edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/[package_name].postinst` and comment everything (or better yet, try to understand it and identify the issue), then try `apt-get` again.

Note that though in this particular question the message concerns "post-installation", it could have mentioned e.g. "pre-removal" or "post-removal" instead (in which cases the extension of the file to be edited would have been `.prerm` or `.postrm`).

Comment: Actually this is the best method. Reinstalling `dpkg` doesn't always help.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I had to fix `/var/lib/dpkg/info/[package_name].prerm` but your post gave me the right direction. Definitely for advanced users though, this is **risky**!

Comment: The best answer. Thanks! Correcting `.prerm` and `.postrm` files fix the problem.

Comment: Finally something that works.  Deleting .prerm file for that package is also an option.  It also works for `.prerm` files etc finally an almost equivalent of `rpm -e --noscripts` :)

Comment: I couldn't remove dokku because of failed instalation on Ubuntu 22.04.1 and this was preventing me doing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Then I commented everything in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/dokku.prerm` and the problem is gone.

Comment: @ArdaBasoglu Ensure to understand what you commented out, or it may lead to other problems.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks

Answer (score 67):

Other than those which you have already posted, there are few other commands which can be helpful.

- Autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files.

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  ```
- Force installation/removal of packages. **☠Use with caution**

  ```
  sudo apt-get --force-yes install <pkgname>
  ```

  and

  ```
  sudo apt-get --force-yes remove <pkgname>
  ```

Also as always, you can use `dpkg` to install, remove and purge packages.

- Install

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i <pkgname>
  ```
- Remove

  ```
  sudo dpkg -r <pkgname>
  ```
- Purge

  ```
  sudo dpkg -P <pkgname>
  ```

Comment: Both dpkg and the apt-get --force-yes commands return the same error as I was getting before. Autoclean doesn't return an error but also doesn't seem to do anything with the two broken packages.

Comment: @Bijak You must have surely tried purging `bsnes` .Have you?

Comment: Yep, with dpkg -P, apt-get purge, and with Synaptic

Comment: Post the output of `dpkg -l |grep bsnes`

Comment: rF  bsnes                                  0.088-7                                       amd64        Accurate SNES/SuperFamicom emulator

Comment: Well that means you haven't removed `bsnes`. try `sudo apt-get purge --force-yes bsnes`

Comment: It exits with an error as soon as it tries to process bsnes (and it does the same thing for the broken Chrome package too). The same error as pasted in the original question

Comment: `E: Command line option --configure is not understood` Isn't --configure only an option for dpkg? I don't see it in the apt-get man page. But dpkg --configure is precisely the step where the error occurs when you do something with apt-get

Comment: Sorry, It was a mistake. Run `sudo dpkg --configure bsnes`

Comment: Yeah, that fails, and is the step at which the apt-get commands fail too. `Setting up bsnes (0.088-7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/bsnes.postinst: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/bsnes.postinst: update-alternatives: not found
dpkg: error processing bsnes (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
`

Comment: sudo apt-get --force-yes remove <pkgname> fixed a botched install of oracle-java7-installer on Linux Mint 18.1 for me.

Comment: `apt-get` wouldn't work for me, because it complained about missing a dependency, which I couldn't install, because /boot was out of space. The `dpkg` way worked for me though - thanks!!

Comment: `sudo dpkg -r evdi-dkms` solved it for me! That package was "stuck" in a failed installation state, causing `sudo apt upgrade` to not work, and all `sudo apt install` commands for anything else to fail.

Answer (score 50):

You can remove the package file in this `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` path and update the source.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/[package_name].*
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, reinstall your package `sudo apt-get install [package_name]`

[Doc](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html)

Comment: Actually you had better use `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/[pakege_name].*`. Otherwise you will also remove packages that start with the same name. Anyways, thanks for this, it was the only solution that worked for me

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spent 30 minutes trying to reverse my install of an incorrect version of libc6 before I found this answer

Comment: Thank you very much for helping resolve this issue quickly.

Comment: The only solution. Other 20 solutions are dummy commands for camuflage

Answer (score 18):

If all else fails. What I did was I first changed the directory to:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
```

then I removed everything with `.postinst`:

```
sudo rm *.postinst
```

then update repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then everything went back to normal when I did:

```
sudo apt-get --force-yes install openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

Comment: This **removes all post-installation scripts** not just that of the affected package. A bit too overzealous in my opinion. -1

Comment: If it's easy to identify and remove only the particular post-install script causing a problem this can be a very convenient way to remove a failing package.

Comment: after a nightmare with kernal issues renaming the .postinst of just the affected kernel fixed the issue

Comment: This ( rm *.postinst ) worked for me after trying a dozen other things. Thanks!

Comment: I did a `mv` of just the single python3 postinst that was causing problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If all else fails, you can manually remove the package through `dpkg`. Running `sudo dpkg -P bsnes` should purge `bsnes`.

Comment: `dpkg: error processing package libcuda1-340 (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal`

Answer (score 4):

In my case  `apt-get install -f` worked. I was installing mysql-workbench-community

Previously tried `apt autoclean`

I saw that dpkg error due to some missing dependencies which could be corrected by installing in forced mode( installing dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation with multiple packages that weren't fully installed and I didn't know what they were. To fix it I followed this answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114193

The steps were:

1. use `sudo dpkg -C` to get the list of all the packages that are in an incomplete state of installation.
2. Edit the list it provides so that it's only 1 line of just the package names.
3. run `sudo dpkg --configure [list of packages separated by spaces]` on all those packages.
4. run `sudo dpkg --configure --pending` to catch the few packages for which step #3 was insufficient.

However, I do wonder if perhaps step #4  is the only step that's
actually needed, or perhaps `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo dpkg --configure --pending` was the single line that would have done the trick. In any case, the 4 steps above solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'
```

Then for each packages which have something other than `ii` in the first and second column, or an `..R` in the third column, remove them using:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all package_name  ## You might need to do this a lot
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Hopefully, this should fix it.

Comment: The `i` character is usually installed state or desired state. There is a description at: [How to interpret the status of dpkg (–list)](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/status-dpkg-list/)

Comment: `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install` by itself might fix things for you (it did for me).

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall coreutils init-system-helpers
```

After running above, you can install/upgrade/remove/purge as usual for any packages.

Comment: This worked in your specific case. But won't work in every case.