# Problems with python-gtk2-dev after update to Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, python, 15.04

Every apt-get operations gives me the following error message:

```
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-gtk2-dev_2.24.0-3ubuntu4_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-gtk2-dev_2.24.0-3ubuntu4_all.deb
```

I tried to remove the package in various ways described here: 
[How to remove/install a package that is not fully installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed)

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
sudo dpkg -P python-gtk2-dev                    
dpkg: error processing package python-gtk2-dev (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-gtk2-dev
```

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-gtk2-dev` also doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to manually uninstall the package as described [here](http://www.piprime.fr/1480/manually-remove-broken-package-debian-ubuntu/):

To manually uninstall the broken package run the two commands below as root in Debian, preceded by sudo in Ubuntu :

```
mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE.* /tmp/
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq PACKAGE
```

where `PACKAGE` is the broken package