# Failure to install any updates (problems with apport and insserv)

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

Lately the updates are not installing, and when I try sudo apt-get upgrade (obviously, after update), I get the errors below. I tried to find solutions on the internet, but most of the explanations were too technical.

I just need someone to tell me what to do as I have no idea of coding or any technical expertise. Here's the whole log from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up apport (2.17.2-0ubuntu1.4) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K15webcit' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'webcit' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service webcit if started
insserv: There is a loop between service webcit and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service ondemand and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service ondemand if started
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service bluetooth at depth 1
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport-gtk:
 apport-gtk depends on apport (>= 0.41); however:
  Package apport is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up at (3.1.16-1ubuntu1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                            insserv: warning: script 'K15webcit' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'webcit' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service webcit if started
insserv: There is a loop between service webcit and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service ondemand and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service ondemand if started
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service bluetooth at depth 1
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting webcit depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package at (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apport
 apport-gtk
 at
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It is NOT a duplicate of How to remove/install a package that is not fully installed? I tried the solutions suggested there but I still got the same error. Besides, that post if full of gobbledy gook. I am NOT a developer and I have no idea of coding. I just need help - desperately!

Is there a way how I can remove the server configuration?

Comment: use this command - $sudo apt-get -f install and the run $sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove/install a package that is not fully installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed)

Comment: I tried apt-get-f, and I got similar errors as above. I cannot post them here as it's too long. In the end, after re-trying apt-get upgrade, I got the following: Errors were encountered while processing:
 apport
 apport-gtk
 at
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate of  How to remove/install a package that is not fully installed? I tried the solutions suggested in that thread but I still got the same error. Besides, that post if full of gobbledy gook. As I said, I am NOT a developer and I have no idea of coding. I just need help - desperately!

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-get install --reinstall insserv`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work! I got the following error: update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package at (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apport
 apport-gtk
 at
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Here's the output of  apt-cache policy insserv: mj@mj:~$ apt-cache policy insserv
insserv:
  Installed: 1.14.0-5ubuntu3
  Candidate: 1.14.0-5ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 1.14.0-5ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: I don't know how to create scripts in /etc/init.d/ :(

Comment: Output of apt-cache policy citadel-webcit: mj@mj:~$ apt-cache policy citadel-webcit
citadel-webcit:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.24-dfsg-1build1
  Version table:
     8.24-dfsg-1build1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packag

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `awk '/Package: citadel/ {system("apt-cache policy "$2)}' /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: You want to remove the installation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29436/discussion-between-mark-j-galea-and-a-b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the problem and the unnecessary package simply start:

```
sudo apt-get purge citadel-webcit
```

After that:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

That's all **;)**

Comment: Thanks a million. You took the time and interest to solve it for me. I will be forever grateful :)