# dpkg: error processing package djview-plugin (--configure):

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

After installing some apps I am getting this error while trying to upgrade :

[image]

```
package is in a very bad inconsistent state;
you should reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

its happening for `sudo apt-get autoremove` too. I tried solutions given in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed).

Please Help me.

NOTE: This error is occurring  after installing GIMP, WINE , Playonlinux , and reinstalling of Mozilla (I did all these continuously one after the other so I don't know specifically.)

Comment: I think it is from reinstall of mozilla firefox.

Comment: I cant even reinstall mozilla : Package operation failed

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall djview-plugin` and then check..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it here [How to fix "Package is in a very bad inconsistent state" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error)

I got it after removing mozilla and

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq djview-plugin
```

and reinstalling mozilla. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands.

Run this command to remove all packages from the package cache

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Run this command to update your source list.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then Try to Fix Broken Packages with this command

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```