# apt-get is broken (error processing package)

Tags: apt, upgrade

I can't do anything with apt-get.  As root, I ran "apt-get clean" (finished quickly and silently).  Then "apt-get update"- which, since I am running an old version (13.?) can't find the repositories and fails.  It used to fail anyway because of this error, which happens when I try to install or remove a package:

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 386770 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing brscan2 (0.2.5-1) ...
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/ALL’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/AL’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother/sane/models2’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother/sane’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package brscan2 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 brscan2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried messing with "brscan2" manually, but haven't been able to fix this.

I am thinking of just putting in a 14.04 or 16.? lts CD and trying to upgrade.  I bet that would fail too.  So- what to do?

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Comment: You can try to
[use or upgrade from old repositories](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: It wouldn't upgrade when the release was current because of this brscan2 problem.  I tried removing brscan2 using apt-get and dpkg.  I tried to remove it manually.  But it's still broken.  Pointing to the old repositories won't help.  But thanks VERY MUCH for taking time to try to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be more verbose - which command did you try?

You can try:

`sudo apt-get -f install`

and

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

*I would use comments if I was allowed to*

Comment: Also, have you tried an `apt-get clean` followed by `apt-get update` ?

Comment: dpkg: error: unknown option --reconfigure

Comment: apt-get clean returns quickly and silently  apt-get update fails the same as attempting to install something

Comment: sorry: I gave wrong option for dpkg command. Corrected above to `dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Please can you paste complete output from ` apt-get update` and `apt-get install <some package>`?

Comment: update can't find the old repositories (but failed when it could too).  The output is WAAAY too long to post.  It's 18K chars beyond the limit.

Comment: root@LEX:/home/bill# apt-get install pyrenamer
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. ...
Removing brscan2 (0.2.5-1) ...
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/ALL’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/AL’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package brscan2 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 brscan2
(edited for length)

Comment: "dpkg --configure -a" returns quickly and silently.

Comment: try `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all brscan2`

Comment: (Reading database ... 386770 files and dir..s currently installed.)
Removing brscan2 (0.2.5-1) ...
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/ALL’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother/sane/models2’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother/sane’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Brother’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package brscan2 (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 brscan2

Comment: Should we move this to CHAT?  That's what I am being prompted to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37790/discussion-between-cybea-and-lunix).

Comment: sorry for huge delay - didnt realize - you couldnt see chat
I think I can not help you much BUT
- you didnt answer what happened with `sudo apt-get -f install`
- I also found this: askubuntu.com/questions/… with more commands to try
- it is hard to help if not getting complete error message - there is something like paste.ubuntu.com you can try

Comment: I mean this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

I recreated the folders using:

```
 sudo mkdir -pv /usr/local/Brother/sane/models2
    mkdir: created directory '/usr/local/Brother'
    mkdir: created directory '/usr/local/Brother/sane'
    mkdir: created directory '/usr/local/Brother/sane/models2'`

 sudo mkdir -pv /usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/ALL
    mkdir: created directory '/usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData'
    mkdir: created directory '/usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/ALL'`

 sudo mkdir -pv /usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/AL
    mkdir: created directory '/usr/local/Brother/sane/GrayCmData/AL'`
```

and then I could cleanly remove the package:

`sudo dpkg -P brscan2`