# delete package with deleted /etc/init.d script (and other dpkg issues)

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, dpkg

I upgraded my system from 14.04 to 16.04 this afternoon and at the completion of the upgrade there were some errors reported--virtual box was having dependency issues and these insserv: errors kept coming up when I tried to do anything with virtual box. One was for a dummy service that I created (I subsequently deleted it and no longer received the error) and the others were related to lpd and das-conductor which is an /etc/init.d script for datameer. . .which I don't think I should have ever tried to install on ubuntu.

To make matters worse I got impatient and just deleted the etc/init.d/das-conductor script and now I can't even remove/purge the program (though I'm not sure I would have been able to before either) I tried to replace the script with this: https://www.datameer.com/documentation/current/Starting+Datameer+at+Boot+Time but it is not set up for ubuntu so I'm still unable to delete datameer and still getting dpkg errors. I guess the first question I have is--can I still get rid of datameer at all? Would this even help??

```
sudo aptitude purge datameer-apache-2.6.0
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
datameer-apache-2.6.0 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 338 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
(Reading database ... 1498119 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing datameer-apache-2.6.0 (5.11.2-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/datameer-apache-2.6.0.prerm: line 5: /etc/init.d/das-conductor: Permission denied
/var/lib/dpkg/info/datameer-apache-2.6.0.prerm: line 6: chkconfig: command not found
dpkg: error processing package datameer-apache-2.6.0 (--purge): subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/datameer-apache-2.6.0.postinst: line 7807: chkconfig: command not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/datameer-apache-2.6.0.postinst: line 7808: chkconfig: command not found
Successfully installed Datameer v5.11.2.
Errors were encountered while processing:
datameer-apache-2.6.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
```

These are all output from the specified commands related to installing virtualbox that I was getting before I started messing around with datameer:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
libgsoap8 libvncserver1 virtualbox-qt
Suggested packages:
vde2 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libgsoap8 libvncserver1 virtualbox virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/21.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 91.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package libgsoap8:amd64.
(Reading database ... 1497994 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgsoap8_2.8.28-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgsoap8:amd64 (2.8.28-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libvncserver1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libvncserver1_0.9.10+dfsg-3build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvncserver1:amd64 (0.9.10+dfsg-3build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox_5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox (5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-qt.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-qt_5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-qt (5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ... 
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libgsoap8:amd64 (2.8.28-1) ...
Setting up libvncserver1:amd64 (0.9.10+dfsg-3build1) ...
Setting up virtualbox (5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1); however:
Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
Package virtualbox-4.3 which provides virtualbox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                      Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
virtualbox
virtualbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up virtualbox (5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1);    however:
Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
Package virtualbox-4.3 which provides virtualbox is not installed.


dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a     followup error from a previous failure.
                     Errors were encountered while processing:
virtualbox
virtualbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [95.7 kB]   
Fetched 190 kB in 0s (223 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up virtualbox (5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1); however:
Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
Package virtualbox-4.3 which provides virtualbox is not installed.


dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                      Errors were encountered while processing:
virtualbox
virtualbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ban@turns:~$ sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
virtualbox* virtualbox-qt*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 89.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 1498314 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-qt (5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for virtualbox-qt (5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
Removing virtualbox (5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for virtualbox (5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
insserv: script lpd: service cups already provided!
insserv: warning: script 'fake_service' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'das-conductor' missing LSB tags and overrides
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing datameer using the method posted by [Skippy le Grand Gourou](https://askubuntu.com/users/136964/skippy-le-grand-gourou) in response to a questions about removal of improperly installed package seems to have worked. https://askubuntu.com/a/632523/485705

I commented out the lines of
/var/lib/dpkg/info/datameer-apache-2.6.0.prerm and was able to remove datameer with apt, then removed the /etc/init.d script. Still having issues with virtual box but I think that is another issue.