# Unable to install any packages on Ubuntu xenial 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, apache2, source-packages

I am trying to install apache2 on Ubuntu xenial 16.04 VM. 
I have added the proxies in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and `/etc/environment`.

The install fails ...

[image]

Comment: See this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed/632523#632523

Comment: It's hard to read the picture of the text on your screen.  If you would use copy and paste it would be substantially easier to help with your issue.  We could copy from the text (if you would provide it) and paste it into search engines to see how similar errors have been resolved.  Also, the Ubuntu system itself will scan the content in the questions and answers and provide suggestions on the side for similar issues and resolutions.