# 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I was trying to install the `cubemap` package, using `sudo apt-get install cubemap`. I can't remember whether I used the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+C while it was installing, or if the package just failed to install.

Anyway, now whenever I turn on my computer from a shutdown, a popup appears in the top left of my screen that says something along the lines of "system problem detected. do you want to report it?"

In addition, whenever I install, remove, upgrade, etc or do anything with apt-get, It will work fine, but at the end, after it finishes, it says `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` I cant remove the cubemap package, and I have tried `apt-get remove cubemap`(returns [this](https://pastebin.com/aEr2iKmL)), I also tried apt-get purging, and apt-get autoremoving cubemap, but none work to remove it.

I know that in the above linked pastebin it says "Package 'cubemap' is not installed, so not removed", but it also says " 1 not fully installed or removed.", and I think that the 1 package not fully removed is cubemap.

EDIT:
[link to the full apt-get session](https://pastebin.com/zAHhFM80)

Comment: dpkg error code 1 covers an enormous number of possibilities. Instead of a summary, please edit your question to show us  the complete apt session with all error messages unedited and in their proper contecxt.

Comment: @user535733 done.

Comment: Read the error message carefully. `cubemap` is not relevant. The problem is `libsimgearcore2017.3.1`, which is not an Ubuntu package. Why do you have it installed? And what source did you get it from?

Comment: The simplest way to resolve for a skilled user is to create the missing directory for the link to work. The simplest way to resolve for an unskilled user is to uninstall all packages from that non-Ubuntu source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `libsimgearcore2017.3.1` package, and it looks to be because the package is not doing adequate env setup/checking during installation.

**Option 1: Safest Cleanup**

It's complaining about a missing directory which is causing a symlink creation to fail.
Try this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/games/flightgear/
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If that doesn't fix it, then it may be looking for another sub directory.
Try this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/games/flightgear/Timezone
sudo apt-get -f install
```

**Option 2: Not safe, or recommended**

`dpkg` has an option for handling removal of packages which are in a broken state. It's a force, so use with care!

> reinstreq
>
> A  package  marked  reinstreq  is  broken  and  requires reinstallation. These packages    cannot    be    removed,     unless     forced     with     option **--force-remove-reinstreq**.

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-remove-reinstreq libsimgearcore2017.3.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Cubemap might be half-installed, try the following:

```
$ dpkg-query --status cubemap
```

It would provide you with some information about the state of the program.

Based on the outcome you can decide to

```
$ dpkg -r cubemap
```

This removes everything except configuration files, or:

```
$ dpkg --purge cubemap
```

This removes everything including configuration files.

Then of course it is up to you whether to reinstall the package again or not, you can use:

```
$ sudo apt install cubemap
```

Answer (score 0):

If a apt-get was interrupted during the installation and a packages database is not setup properly, it is best to reinstall the packages manual.

The reason is, that apt/apt-get does not recover from a "... not fully installed or removed" state. So do the following steps and see if the apt-get works after that:

```
# Download the library package
wget http://url.to.the.package/libsimgearcore2017.3.1.deb
# Since the package installer is broken, create the flightgear folder (if Timezone is the link)
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/games/flightgear
# Manually install the package
sudo dpkg -i libsimgearcore2017.3.1.deb
# Check and reinstall cubemap
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt-get install cubemap
# If it does not work, retry with fix missing
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
```

Answer (score -1):

Synaptic Package Manager or `gksu nautilus`.
These allow elevated (sudo) permissions to access the file system on Ubuntu with a GUI.

For terminal procedures try the following:

To find if cubemap is installed:

```
dpkg -l | cubemap
```

To check which packages are missing, edit with `nano`or `vim` or `gedit`:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/cubemap.postinst
```

but since you don't know if it was post-install or pre-remove problem you might have to check and edit:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/cubemap.prerm `
```

There are few other commands which can be helpful.

Autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files.

```
`sudo apt-get autoclean`
```

Force installation/removal of packages. **☠Use with caution**

```
sudo apt-get --force-yes install <pkgname>
```

and

```
`sudo apt-get --force-yes remove <pkgname>`
```

Also as always, you can use `dpkg` to install, remove and purge packages.This is what Synaptic Package Manager facilitates with its GUI.

Install

```
sudo dpkg -i <pkgname>
```

Remove

```
sudo dpkg -r <pkgname>
```

Purge

```
sudo dpkg -P <pkgname>
```

Similar Q&A here: [How to remove/install a package that is not fully installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed/438365#438365)

Comment: Please edit your answer and use the { } icon on top of the edit window to mark the lines of code.