# Consistant Error While Removing Package

Tags: package-management, dpkg, uninstall, lyx

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10. Recently I tired using LyX. In the the how-to I read regarding using LyX with Hebrew, I was advised to install a package called 'ivirtex'.

After I understood that it was not needed. But whenever I try to remove it it raises this error:

```
dpkg: error processing package ivritex (--remove): 
 installed ivritex package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ivritex
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I already tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo --configure -a
```

both didn't work. Also, Whenever I try to install another package, I encounter the same error regarding 'iviritex' package.

Any way to forcefully remove this package?

The full output:

```
chicko@gal-chicko:~$ sudo apt remove ivritex
Reading package lists... 0%
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ivritex
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 3,134 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 220599 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ivritex (1.2.1-1) ...
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebtech.cls to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebtech.cls.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebcal.sty to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebcal.sty.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebfont.sty to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebfont.sty.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebrew_newcode.sty to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebrew_newcode.sty.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebrew_oldcode.sty to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebrew_oldcode.sty.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebrew_p.sty to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebrew_p.sty.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/8859-8.def to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/8859-8.def.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/cp1255.def to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/cp1255.def.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/cp862.def to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/cp862.def.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lheenc.def to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lheenc.def.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/rlbabel.def to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/rlbabel.def.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/si960.def to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/si960.def.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lheclas.fd to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lheclas.fd.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lhecmr.fd to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lhecmr.fd.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lhecmss.fd to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lhecmss.fd.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lhecmtt.fd to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lhecmtt.fd.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lhecrml.fd to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lhecrml.fd.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lhefr.fd to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lhefr.fd.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lheredis.fd to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lheredis.fd.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lheshold.fd to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lheshold.fd.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lheshscr.fd to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lheshscr.fd.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lheshstk.fd to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/lheshstk.fd.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebrew.ldf to /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/hebrew.ldf.tetex by ivritex', none removed.
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
Regenerating '/var/lib/texmf/updmap.cfg-DEBIAN'... 

Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/20culmus-latex.cfg

done.
Regenerating '/var/lib/texmf/updmap.cfg-TEXLIVEDIST'... done.
update-updmap has updated the following file(s):
    /var/lib/texmf/updmap.cfg-DEBIAN
    /var/lib/texmf/updmap.cfg-TEXLIVEDIST
If you want to activate the changes in the above file(s),
you should run updmap-sys or updmap.
updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /home/chicko) to root's actual home (/root).
updmap [ERROR]: Either -sys or -user mode is required.
updmap [ERROR]: In nearly all cases you should use updmap -sys.
updmap [ERROR]: For special cases see http://tug.org/texlive/scripts-sys-user.html
dpkg: error processing package ivritex (--remove):
 installed ivritex package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ivritex
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking farther and farther, I encountered this question at last:
[How to remove/install a package that is not fully installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed)

The 5th answer suggested I do this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/[package_name].*
```

After that, I just needed to redo:

```
sudo apt-get remove [package_name]
```

And everything else worked again, thank the lord.

Comment: This is dangerous to do unless you know what you're doing.  This may also leave some bits still alive, because the prerm and postrm scripts can be set to do some cleanup - removing those can problematic.