# Dependency problem libsensors4

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I just tried upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. The upgrade seems to have been successful. However, I cannot get away with dependency problems with `libsensors4`.

Running `sudo apt upgrade` yields:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
 lm-sensors : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And `sudo apt --fix-broken install` yields:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
 lm-sensors : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I have tried installing `libsensors4`, but I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libsensors4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libsensors4:i386 libsensors-config

E: Package 'libsensors4' has no installation candidate
```

Running `sudo apt list libgl1-mesa-dri` yields:

```
Listing... Done
libgl1-mesa-dri/now 1:20.0~git200108124800.ad4fb7e~b~padoka0 amd64 [installed,local]
libgl1-mesa-dri/focal-updates,focal-security 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2 i386
```

I cannot install anything through apt anymore. I saw related problems appearing in several other questions, but for some reason none of the answers allowed me to solve the problem. Thanks in advance for your help, would be happy to provide more info if required!

**Edit**
The output of `apt-cache rdepends lm-sensors` is

```
lm-sensors
Reverse Depends:
  libsensors-config
  libsensors4
  inxi
  libsensors5
  libsensors-config
  libsensors5
```

and the output of `apt-cache rdepends libgl1-mesa-dri` is

```
libgl1-mesa-dri
Reverse Depends:
  qml-module-qtquick2
  libwine
  libglx-mesa0
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
  xserver-xorg-core
  xserver-xorg-core
  xserver-xephyr
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  libglx-mesa0
  xserver-xorg-core
  xserver-xorg-core
  xserver-xephyr
  xserver-xorg
  libglx-mesa0
  xorg
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
```

Finally, here is the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'`: https://pastebin.com/2zyg4mHB

Comment: Sometime between 18.04 and 20.04, `libsensors4` was superseded by `libsensors5`. Newer packages do not depend upon older wrong-version packages. This looks like a classic symptom of an **un**successful release-upgrade.

Comment: Please edit your post with the output of `apt-cache rdepends lm-sensors` and `apt-cache rdepends libgl1-mesa-dri` .

Comment: And also the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'` .

Comment: The Version of the package libgl1-mesa-dri (64-bit/32-bit) are not the same.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @rusty I just updated the post as suggested, hope this helps!

Comment: See if `sudo dpkg --configure -a` followed by `sudo apt install --fix-broken` work.

Comment: Rom1P also make sure you backup all your important files.

Comment: @rusty thanks again, the first command did not produce any output and the second one gave the same output as in the original post. I indeed did a backup just in case.

Comment: Rom1P I noticed `xfce4-volumed` package in the list, does that mean you are using Xubuntu. In that case is the application `Synaptic Package Manager` available in your computer? If yes, solving the broken package problem is much easier.

Comment: @rusty unfortunately I don't think I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we begin, make sure you have backed up all your important files.

The output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'` shows a lot of files with `rc` in their first column. The meaning of these characters can be studied [here](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/status-dpkg-list/). In short:

**First character**: The first character signifies the desired state.

```
u: Unknown (an unknown state)
i: Install (marked for installation)
r: Remove (marked for removal)
p: Purge (marked for purging)
h: Hold
```

**Second Character**: The second character signifies the current state, whether it is installed or not. The possible values are:

```
n: Not- The package is not installed
i: Inst – The package is successfully installed
c: Cfg-files – Configuration files are present
u: Unpacked- The package is stilled unpacked
f: Failed-cfg- Failed to remove configuration files
h: Half-inst- The package is only partially installed
W: trig-aWait
t: Trig-pend
```

**Third Character**: This corresponds to the error state. The possible value include:

```
R: Reinst-required The package must be installed.
```

All the packages in you list are marked `rc`, and are marked for removal but for some reasons `apt` is not able to remove them. Lets try to resolve this ourselves:

1. Open up a terminal window and enter the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. If this did not work, try `sudo dpkg --remove -a`. These should be followed by `sudo apt install --fix-broken` command. If this did not fix your problem, go to step 2.
2. Save the following bash script to a file named `remove_conflicting_pkgs.sh`.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   while read ; do
       dpkg --remove --force-all "$REPLY" || echo "$REPLY" >> 00__REMOVAL_FAILED.list
   done << __EOF
   acl
   apg
   apt-offline
   apturl-common
   bluejeans-v2
   cmake-data
   colord
   debian-archive-keyring
   deja-dup
   dell-eula
   dell-recovery-bootloader
   dmraid
   gconf2
   gnome-initial-setup
   gnome-paint
   gnustep-base-runtime
   gnustep-common
   gtk-recordmydesktop
   hplip
   icedtea-netx
   icedtea-netx-common
   kpartx-boot
   libbonobo2-0
   libbonobo2-common
   libgnome2-common
   libgnomevfs2-common
   libgtk-3-0
   libgvc6
   libqtcore4
   libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
   libsane-common
   libsane-hpaio
   libsane1
   libsane1
   libsensors4
   libsensors4
   libsnmp-base
   libthunarx-2-0
   linux-image-4.15.0-1043-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1073-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1076-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1079-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1080-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1081-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1087-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1090-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1091-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1093-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1094-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1096-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1097-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1099-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1100-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1101-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-1103-oem
   linux-image-4.15.0-122-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-123-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-126-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-128-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-129-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-135-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-136-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-139-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-140-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-141-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-143-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-144-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-147-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-153-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-154-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-156-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-158-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-161-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-161-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-162-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-162-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-163-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-163-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-166-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-166-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-167-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-167-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-169-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-169-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-171-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-171-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-173-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-173-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-175-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-175-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-176-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-176-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-177-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-177-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-180-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-180-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-184-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-184-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-187-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-187-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-188-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-188-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-189-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-189-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-191-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-191-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-192-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-192-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-193-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-193-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-194-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-194-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-196-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-196-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-197-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-197-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-200-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-200-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-201-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-201-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-202-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-202-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-204-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-204-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-206-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-206-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-208-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-208-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-209-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-209-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-210-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-210-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-211-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-211-lowlatency
   linux-image-4.15.0-212-generic
   linux-image-4.15.0-212-lowlatency
   linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-104-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-105-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-107-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-109-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-110-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-113-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-117-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-120-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-121-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-122-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-124-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-125-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-126-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-128-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-131-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-132-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-135-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-136-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-137-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-139-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-144-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-146-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-147-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-148-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-149-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-150-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-59-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-65-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-66-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-67-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-70-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-71-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-72-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-73-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-74-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-80-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-81-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-84-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-86-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-87-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-89-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-90-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-91-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-92-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-94-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-97-generic
   linux-image-5.4.0-99-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1043-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1073-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1076-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1079-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1080-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1081-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1087-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1090-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1091-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1093-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1094-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1096-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1097-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1099-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1100-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1101-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-1103-oem
   linux-modules-4.15.0-122-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-123-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-126-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-128-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-129-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-135-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-136-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-139-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-140-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-141-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-142-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-143-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-144-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-147-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-151-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-153-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-154-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-156-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-158-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-161-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-161-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-162-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-162-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-163-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-163-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-166-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-166-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-167-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-167-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-169-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-169-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-171-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-171-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-173-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-173-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-175-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-175-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-176-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-176-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-177-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-177-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-180-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-180-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-184-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-184-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-187-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-187-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-188-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-188-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-189-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-189-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-191-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-191-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-192-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-192-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-193-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-193-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-194-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-194-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-196-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-196-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-197-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-197-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-200-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-200-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-201-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-201-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-202-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-202-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-204-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-204-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-206-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-206-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-208-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-208-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-209-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-209-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-210-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-210-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-211-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-211-lowlatency
   linux-modules-4.15.0-212-generic
   linux-modules-4.15.0-212-lowlatency
   linux-modules-5.4.0-100-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-104-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-105-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-107-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-109-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-110-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-113-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-117-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-120-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-121-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-122-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-124-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-125-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-126-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-128-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-131-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-132-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-135-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-136-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-137-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-139-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-144-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-146-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-147-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-148-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-149-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-150-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-58-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-59-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-65-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-66-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-67-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-70-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-71-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-72-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-73-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-74-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-77-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-80-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-81-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-84-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-86-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-87-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-89-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-90-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-91-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-92-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-94-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-96-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-97-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-99-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-122-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-123-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-126-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-128-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-129-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-135-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-136-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-139-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-140-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-141-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-142-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-143-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-144-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-147-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-151-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-153-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-154-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-156-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-158-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-159-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-161-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-162-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-163-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-166-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-167-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-169-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-171-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-173-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-175-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-176-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-177-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-180-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-184-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-187-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-188-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-189-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-191-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-192-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-193-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-194-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-196-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-197-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-200-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-201-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-202-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-204-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-206-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-208-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-209-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-210-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-211-generic
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-212-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-100-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-104-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-105-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-107-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-109-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-110-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-113-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-117-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-120-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-121-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-122-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-124-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-125-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-126-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-128-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-131-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-132-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-135-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-136-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-137-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-139-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-144-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-146-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-147-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-148-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-149-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-150-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-59-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-65-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-66-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-67-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-70-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-71-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-72-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-73-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-74-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-77-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-80-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-81-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-84-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-86-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-87-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-89-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-90-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-91-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-92-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-94-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-96-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-97-generic
   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-99-generic
   locale-support-plugin
   metacity-common
   mysql-common
   odbcinst
   oem-config
   oem-config-gtk
   oem-fix-bt-intel-tlp-blacklist-cyclonepeak2-bt
   oem-fix-eth-realtek-disabletlpr8153
   oem-workaround-ubiquity-no-early-microcode
   printer-driver-gutenprint
   python
   sane
   sane-utils
   tlp
   tlp-rdw
   tlp-sensible
   ubuntu-system-service
   vlc-plugin-notify
   vlc-plugin-qt
   vlc-plugin-samba
   vlc-plugin-skins2
   vlc-plugin-video-splitter
   vlc-plugin-visualization
   wine-stable
   wine-stable-amd64
   wine-stable-i386
   wine-staging
   wine-staging-amd64
   wine-staging-i386
   xfce4-volumed
   __EOF
   ```

   And, then open up a terminal window. `cd` to the directory where you have saved the script. Now run the script as: `sudo bash remove_conflicting_pkgs.sh` . The removal of all packages will take time as you have about 473 packages to get rid of. So, be patient and wait until the script finishes. The packages for which the command `dpkg --remove --force-all pkg_name` failed will be *appended* to the file `00__REMOVAL_FAILED.list` in the same directory as the `remove_conflicting_pkgs.sh` script. After you remove all these packages, run `sudo apt install --fix-broken` . And, that should be it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. The first two commands did not produce any output, and the third one produced the same output as before. I ran your script, and got some warning saying (for each package in the list) request ignored, only configuration files are installed, use --purge to remove them as well. I hence replaced the --remove with --purge in your script and ran again. The output of `sudo apt install --fix-broken` was: https://pastebin.com/fYxY5BXa . Do you think I should just reinstall a fresh version of Ubuntu at this point? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Rom1P When you have a broken package problem [these are the remedies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed/1450732) to try, if you don't have something like `Synaptic Package Manager` pre-installed. If nothing works out, a clean install would be your only choice perhaps.

Comment: thank you again for your help, I ended up re-installing everything, I did not manage to apply the remedies you mentioned. Thanks a lot!