Unable to update kernel on Ubuntu 22.04 due to cpio write error, but /boot is not full
NEW INFO 6/13/24 16:18 MT: after main post
Having problems with apt upgrade on my main workstation, been troubleshooting for months and I can't figure this out. Kernel will not update. Need the machine, so I keep restoring from backups when my troubleshooting invariably borks the machine, but I need help figuring this out. I know this is a long post, but please read through and see if you have any suggestions. I don't want to admit defeat and do a clean install, but I'm at a loss. Not ready to take the plunge for 24.04 yet.
Running Ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS on a Ryzen 5700X w/64G RAM. A few months ago I started getting "update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic; cpio: write error: No space left on device; E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 2" when I would try to do an apt upgrade. I also see that initramfs-tools post installation script returns exit code of 1. Normally I'd expect I was running out of space in /boot, however on my system /boot is part of /, and has about 44G free. /boot/efi is its own 512M fat32 filesystem with 505M free. In fact, nothing is full, as you can see below:
root@jaeger:~# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              6.3G  2.7M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-lv_root        49G  3.0G   44G   7% /
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-lv_usr         20G  7.9G   11G  43% /usr
tmpfs                               32G   73M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs                           128K   47K   77K  38% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
tmpfs                               32G     0   32G   0% /run/qemu
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-lv_tmp        9.8G   19M  9.3G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-lv_var         20G   14G  4.6G  76% /var
/dev/mapper/vgdata-lvdata          1.9T  1.4T  353G  81% /data
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-lv_nfs_stub   3.8M   72K  3.4M   3% /nfs
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-lv_home       492G  146G  321G  32% /home
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-lv_var_log    2.0G  598M  1.3G  32% /var/log
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-lv_var_tmp    974M  622M  285M  69% /var/tmp
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-lv_var_audit  488M   24K  452M   1% /var/log/audit
/dev/nvme0n1p1                     511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
kaiju:/t3/cvw                       15T  6.2T  7.6T  45% /nfs/cvw
worknas:/volume1/homes             3.6T  1.4T  2.3T  39% /nfs/worknas/homes
media:/volume1/music                13T  6.6T  6.1T  52% /nfs/media/music
media:/volume1/video                13T  6.6T  6.1T  52% /nfs/media/video
worknas:/volume1/Work              3.6T  1.4T  2.3T  39% /nfs/worknas/Work
kaiju:/t3/cvo                       15T  6.2T  7.6T  45% /nfs/cvo
worknas:/volume1/repositories      3.6T  1.4T  2.3T  39% /nfs/worknas/repositories
tmpfs                              6.3G  144K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000


"apt update" runs normally, but when I run an "apt upgrade -y" I get the following:
root@jaeger:~# apt upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  snapd
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gir1.2-vte-2.91 gnome-remote-desktop libvte-2.91-0 libvte-2.91-common linux-firmware
5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
3 standard LTS security updates
Need to get 267 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,549 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.31 [267 MB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libvte-2.91-0 amd64 0.68.0-1ubuntu0.1 [214 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libvte-2.91-common amd64 0.68.0-1ubuntu0.1 [9,408 B]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 gir1.2-vte-2.91 amd64 0.68.0-1ubuntu0.1 [10.7 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 gnome-remote-desktop amd64 42.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [128 kB]
Fetched 267 MB in 6s (46.3 MB/s)               
(Reading database ... 237804 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.31_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.31) over (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.30) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libvte-2.91-0_0.68.0-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvte-2.91-0:amd64 (0.68.0-1ubuntu0.1) over (0.68.0-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libvte-2.91-common_0.68.0-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvte-2.91-common (0.68.0-1ubuntu0.1) over (0.68.0-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-vte-2.91_0.68.0-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-vte-2.91:amd64 (0.68.0-1ubuntu0.1) over (0.68.0-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-remote-desktop_42.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-remote-desktop (42.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) over (42.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up libvte-2.91-common (0.68.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.31) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
cpio: write error: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 2
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libvte-2.91-0:amd64 (0.68.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up gnome-remote-desktop (42.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up gir1.2-vte-2.91:amd64 (0.68.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.8) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
cpio: write error: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 2
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Listing the Linux Kernels, I see plenty of old config files, but the only fully installed kernel is 6.5.0-26. I got partial installs on 27, 28 and 35 at one point, but removed them in an effort to fix this problem. 6.5.0-26 is the only recent kernel that has worked.
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic                 5.15.0-25.25                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-58-generic                 5.15.0-58.64                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-60-generic                 5.15.0-60.66                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic                 5.19.0-32.33~22.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic                 5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic                 5.19.0-38.39~22.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic                 5.19.0-40.41~22.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-41-generic                 5.19.0-41.42~22.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-42-generic                 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-43-generic                 5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic                 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-50-generic                 5.19.0-50.50                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic                  6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-31-generic                  6.2.0-31.31~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic                  6.2.0-32.32~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-33-generic                  6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-34-generic                  6.2.0-34.34~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic                  6.2.0-35.35~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic                  6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic                  6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic                  6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic                  6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-15-generic                  6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic                  6.5.0-17.17~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic                  6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-21-generic                  6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-6.5.0-25-generic                  6.5.0-25.25~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic                  6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-6.5.0-27-generic                  6.5.0-27.28~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-6.5.0-28-generic                  6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-6.5.0-35-generic                  6.5.0-35.35~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic


I've tried multiple things to resolve this, and I've restored the system from backup many times.  Things I've tried:

"apt autoremove" and "apt --purge autoremove" will not get rid of the old Kernel config files, mkintramfs fails with the cpio 2 and initramfs-tools shows the post-installation return code of 1
Forcing reconfig with dpkg

dpkg --configure -a
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.31) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
cpio: write error: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 2
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
cpio: write error: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 2
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools


Purged all old kernels manual with apt --purge linux-image-version.numbers-generic. Purged the newer 27-35 kernels that way, too. Kernels were removed successfully, but didn't fix issue. Restored from backup since then.
Same thing, but with dpkg instead of apt
Moved main partition, created 1GB ext4 partition between EFI and main partition and assigned to boot. Moved stuff out of /boot on / and into /boot2, edited /etc/fstab to mount /boot then /boot/efi. Booted, but did not solve issue, restored from backup.
Reviewed /var/log/apt/history.log and term.log, didn't see any more detailed info
Reviewed dmesg, didn't see anything.
Ran "dmesg -w" while running "apt update" and "apt upgrade". While running "apt update" I saw several audit: type=1400 audit(1718299437.000:129): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="ubuntu_pro_esm_cache//dpkg" name="/var/lib/dpkg/arch" pid=70226 comm="dpkg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0, but nothing during the "apt upgrade". Ran "systemctl stop apparmor" to disable apparmor and tried the update again, no dmesg errors but still no joy.
Several variations of purging / reinstalling linux-firmware. It never goes well, invariably revert to backup.

====
NEW INFO 6/13/24 16:18 MT:
I've cleaned up all the old kernels with the following commands:
dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/{print $2}')
dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/^ic/{print $2}')
Now only one Kernel (dangerous, I know, but it was the only working one anyway). dpkg --configure -a shows me the same errors. This is the most concise way I know to show the problem:
root@jaeger:~# dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic                  6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
root@jaeger:~# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.31) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
cpio: write error: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 2
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
cpio: write error: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 2
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools

FYI, also updated BIOS on my MSI B550A-PRO from BIOS E7C56AMS.AE1 (06/09/2023) to E7C56AMS.AI1 (04/30/2024) earlier today, no change. The old BIOS was in place long before my problems started.

dpkg -l | head -n 5 gives you the dpkg header, which tells you the coding used for the first column (up to three characters). If I do dpkg -l | grep linux-image I see one specific kernel, and a "hwe"-line for the same kernel. No ic or rc lines - so those looks very odd to me, on top of there being so many of them.

sudo apt-get autoremove --purge; sudo apt-get -y autoclean ?

@Hannu, no joy. fails with the same set of errors on the update that we see in the other attempts, starting when update-initramfs generates the new kernel. I agree, really weird that it still has all of the old kernels with just the config files. The kernel itself isn't there, not taking up space.

apt purge ,or apt remove --purge , then manually rm leftovers in /lib/modules.

@ubfan1, those options give me the same errors.
I tried suggestions in https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed. I removed /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-firmware.* and initramfs-tools.*, then did a apt purge on both those packages, then an apt update, then an apt install on both. Same results.
One thing that confuses me is the cpio error with no space on device, when I clearly have space on my devices. I don't know where to look to determine WHERE cpio is trying to write.

Added new info to bottom of main post, followed suggestions provided so far and chased down more info that lead to. Still no luck.

I finally gave up and did a fresh install of 24.04. Still no idea why this problem occurred, but I now have no way to go back and try any solutions, so we'll call it closed.

Recently, I had a similar issue on Debian 12. Somehow, the cpio package became corrupted. By executing apt remove cpio I uninstalled the cpio package. This change lead to removal of few more packages (initramfs-tools) and automatically suggested installing cpio:i386 (Multiarch is required as a prerequisite) and dracut. dracut was able to successfully unpack and generate the kernel images.
I also uninstalled the kernel images and installed them again (no reboot in between), but this step was probably not required.
